# Sort values made up of an integer followed by % sign

Tags: javascript, sorting, protractor

I have a md-table column with values -

```
Length,Class
Weight
Length,Width,Height
```

and one more column with values -

```
1%
5%
38%
```

When I try to sort these columns in both ascending and descending order it doesn't give me the correct result.

I am using arrayname.sort() for ascending and arrayname.reverse() for descending sort.

It sorts like this -

desc - ['Length,Width,Height','Length,Class','Weight'];
desc - ['1%','38%',5%];

Other columns are sorting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript sorting is based on unicode value, so it can be finicky in some cases.  Especially when dealing with integers, they aren't quite the way you would expect them i.e:

```
var c = ["38%", "1%", "5%"]
c.sort() // ["1%", "38%", "5%"] not what you wanted
```

Same example using integers instead of a string of numbers:

```
var c = [5, 1, 38];
c.sort() // [1, 38, 5] also not what you want
```

However, you should be able to create a simple sort function that would work for most cases.  Something along the lines of this:

```
var c = [5, 1, 38];
c.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a-b;
})
// [1, 5, 38] this is what you would expect/want
```

It still won't work properly with the % due to unicode values:

```
var c = ["38%", "1%", "5%"];
c.sort(function(a,b) {
   return a-b;
});
["38%", "1%", "5%"] // not what you want
```

But you could just slice that % before you perform the sort.  Take a look at the examples on [MDN Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), they cover a lot of different scenarios.